# Rest api route name when dealing with user specific data

Tags: web-services, rest, http

I have restful service and I'm trying to follow the best practices. I was wondering what is the best practice when naming a resource that returns data for a specific user. The user is authenticated with a Token sent in the header.

I need to get all the favorites of a specific user.

Examples:

myservice.com/Favorites -> I get the user with the token and then query the favorites, but it seems weird, i would expect /Favorites to return all favorites of any user.

myservice.com/MyFavorites -> MyFavorites is not really an entity, but that would make things clearer.

myservice.com/Favorites?userId=123 -> This one is clear, but it feels redundant to send the userId since I already know the user with the token.

Is there any other way to do this? What is the best practice?

Comment: Found any answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are valid and of the three you mention, I like the 3rd, However...  but I'd suggest a different pattern for your needs:

```
https://myservice.com/user/123/favorites
```

Also, stick to all lowercase in your resource urls.

Tokens are fine authentication, but you might have a need where a user might be a 'super user' and would need to hit other user resources for example.